# Can any one suggests some platform agnostic bot framework

Tags: bots, botframework, chatbot, platform-agnostic

I am looking for a **platform agnostic** framework or library that can give me a generalise schema for different responses coming from Messenger, Slack, Web chat, Skype etc. And, i can reply them with a single schema.

So, Any bot framework that have its own request and response schema.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/)? It's exactly what you are looking at.

The [Microsoft Bot Framework](http://dev.botframework.com) provides just what you need to build and connect intelligent bots that interact naturally wherever your users are talking, from text/sms to [Skype](https://www.skype.com/en/developer/), [Slack](https://api.slack.com/bot-users), [Kik](https://bots.kik.com/#/), Office 365 mail and other popular services.

The Bot Framework has a number of components including the Bot Connector, Bot Builder SDK, and the Bot Directory.

### Resources

- [Microsoft Bot Framework Developer Portal](http://dev.botframework.com)
- [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/)
- [Bot Builder SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder)
- [Task-focused Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-samples)
- [Azure Bot Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/bot-service)
- [Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/debug-bots-emulator)

Comment: is it gonna support multi-tenancy also?